# I don't have models.Model.objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, windows, django-models

For some reason I can do almost everything on Django but access to model.objects, like, it doesn't even appear, I cannot delete nor find anything without that (or I do not know how), I'm learning Django from a basic course.
I use Python 3.11, Django 4.1.4, on Pycharm 2022.3.

PD:
If you know of another way of doing the Create, Read, Update and Delete of objects I would appreciate that.

Sorry for the English.

I tried searching on the web about this problem but since I'm a noob on Django and trainee on Python most things are like white noise to me, like, I don't understand.

Comment: what does your import look like?

Comment: from django.db import models

#Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 0):

It does work, it's just that Pycharm does not detect the .objects functions, I do not know why though.